# google maps sky api v3

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I am looking for a way to use Google Maps API V3 to display a [night sky map](http://www.google.com/intl/it/sky/), but it seems that Google itself still uses V2, which will be discontinued as soon as May, the 19th, 2013.

Google Maps API V2 [allows you to choose](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/v2/reference#GMapType) various night sky representations in the `GMapType` class.

Google Maps API V3 only admits `HYBRID`, `ROADMAP`, `SATELLITE`, `TERRAIN`.

Is there any way to use V3 to display Google Sky?

Answer (score 3):

Even though there's no SKY map type in v3, you can retrieve the Sky maptiles directly. There's an example of using the Sky data in the Maps API Demo Gallery which uses the v3 API.

http://gmaps-samples-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/planetary-maptypes/planetary-maptypes.html

```
mapTypes['sky'] = {
       getTileUrl: function(coord, zoom) {
        return getHorizontallyRepeatingTileUrl(coord, zoom, function(coord, zoom) {
          return "http://mw1.google.com/mw-planetary/sky/skytiles_v1/" +
                 coord.x + "_" + coord.y + '_' + zoom + '.jpg';

        });
      },
      tileSize: new google.maps.Size(256, 256),
      isPng: false,
      maxZoom: 13,
      radius: 57.2957763671875,
      name: 'Sky',
      credit: 'Image Credit: SDSS, DSS Consortium, NASA/ESA/STScI'
    };
```

Answer (score 1):

Not at the moment. Even google's own sky map page is in v.2: http://www.google.com/sky